# Assigning a Method in WSGI/Python

Tags: wsgi, werkzeug

Hi I'm going through a [Werkzeug tutorial](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/) and I'm a little confused about the statement: `app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/static':  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
})`

Contained inside:

```
class Shortly(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.redis = redis.Redis(config['redis_host'], config['redis_port'])

    def dispatch_request(self, request):
        return Response('Hello World!')

    def wsgi_app(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        response = self.dispatch_request(request)
        return response(environ, start_response)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)


def create_app(redis_host='localhost', redis_port=6379, with_static=True):
    app = Shortly({
        'redis_host':       redis_host,
        'redis_port':       redis_port
    })
    if with_static:
        app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
            '/static':  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
        })
    return app
```

What's going on there? Why is app.wsgi_app being assigned to whatever SharedDataMiddleware is returning? I mean, isn't app.wsgi_app just a method name?

Any insight will be appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** In this example an extra functionality is added to the `Shortly` app by wrapping its entry point with a `SharedDataMiddleware` object.

### Long explanation

`app.wsgi_app` is not a method *name*. It's rather a reference to the method. And since Python is pretty dynamic language, one can replace any object's methods after this object was created.

Let's consider a simple example:

```
class App:
    def run(self, param):
        print(param)

app = App()
app.run('foo')  # prints 'foo'        

original_run = app.run  # save a reference to the original run method

def run_ex(param):
    print('run_ex')      # add our extra functionality
    original_run(param)  # call the original one

app.run = run_ex
app.run('foo')  # prints 'run_ex' and then 'foo'
```

So, in such way one can easy replace app's method `run` with a regular function.

Now, let's go back to `Werkzeug`. As you know from the [`WSGI` specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/), an application must be a *callable* with a specific signature. And `Shortly`'s `wsgi_app` method is the desired callable. However, somebody wants to add an extra functionality to the `Shortly` app via `SharedDataMiddleware` middleware. If you [look closer](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/1a21e27a99331d854cec9174a1fc0fcd9717a673/werkzeug/wsgi.py#L434) to it, you'll see, that it's a regular class with a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method. Hence, all objects of `SharedDataMiddleware` class can be called.

```
middleware = SharedDataMiddleware(...)  # create an object
middleware(...)  # call the object. It can be slightly confusing at a first glance
```

So, for now you can see that any objects of `SharedDataMiddleware` is a `WSGI` applications by itself. And since you already know how to replace `app`'s main method `wsgi_app`, the only one thing you have to do - is to store a reference to the original method `Shortly.wsgi_app` to be able to call it later. It's done by passing it to the `SharedDataMiddleware` constructor.